# Android email intent and message body

Tags: android

I'm using intent to launch email application from my application. I set subject, short message and email address using the intent. Everything works fine except that cursor position in the email message section. My email message is like "Thank for choosing ......
.................
Do not write below this line.

I see the message in the email body, but my cursor is blinking below the "Do not write ..." line. How can i make the cursor appear before my message, so that user can just start to type.

Here is my code

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ getResources().getString(R.string.helpSenderAddress)});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getResources().getString(R.string.helpSubject));
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.helpMessage),Build.VERSION.RELEASE,getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),0).versionCode));
```

Answer (score 8):

I hate answering like this, but: you can't. You can't control how an arbitrary other program will act once it fulfills the intent.

Comment: boooo say it ain't so.  I launched the e-mail client and the cursor is up in the "to" field instead of down in the message body... anyway to change that 2 years later?

Comment: That is *as long as the arbitrary program doesn't provide an interface (an Intent Key) for doing so*. Which unfortunately is currently not the case in the `ACTION_SEND` or `_SENDTO`.