# Setting the cursor to end of the body in Gmail Android Programatically

Tags: android, gmail

I needed to send email programatically with some info in the body of email.
User will add more info after the info I added programtically in body of email. I can now send the email with the text in the body.
Now the problem is that when email intent is opened the text I added is shows in body of email but the cursor is at start of that field. All I want to do is to move it to the end of the text I added. So that users can easily add their info into it. Is it possible? If so how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android email intent and message body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940640/android-email-intent-and-message-body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is possible since the `Intent` leads to the Mail application and you surely cannot change its code. The better solution from the user experience point of view will be to create a form so your users can enter all required data inside your application, without the need to alter e-mail message contents. Hope this helps.